# qed symbol error

Tags: errors, packages

I may have misunderstood the documentation, but I believe that if I use the `amsmath` package in the declaration, then typing `\qed` should give me a Q.E.D. symbol. When I do this, it crashes with `undefined control sequence`.

The snippet:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/texfiles/}}
\begin{document}
...
Since we proved that any function with the property ($\pi$) is an increasing involution, we have thus proved that $f(x) = x$ is the only function which satisfies ($\pi$). 
\qed
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 12):

You need the `amsthm` package for that:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/texfiles/}}
\begin{document}
...
Since we proved that any function with the property ($\pi$) is an increasing involution,
we have thus proved that $f(x) = x$ is the only function which satisfies ($\pi$). 
\qed
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I adjust the symbol's placement? (Edit: never mind, I found that out. Thank you!)

Comment: You may add that the QED symbol is added automatically in the `proof` environment and that there's `\qedhere` for particular cases, when the proof ends with an alignment environment or a list.