# How to make qed box inside alignment environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, alignment, setspace

My proof that I need to write is very short that it only consists of one alignment. Therefore, I want to put the qed box inside the alignment indented to the rightmost.

If I simply put `\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}` inside alignment environment, it does not indent to the end of the line.

```
\begin{align*}
    &= \textrm{a math equation here}\\
    &= \textrm{aligned properly}\\
    &= \textrm{blah blah blah}\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I also tried to vertically space it using `setspace` package, however, it only seems to move any lines below it and not the square:

```
\begin{align*}
    &= \textrm{a math equation here}\\
    &= \textrm{aligned properly}\\
    &= \textrm{blah blah blah}
\end{align*}
\vspace{-12px}
\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}\\
More text here to compare blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

[image]

Also, it would be nice if I get put the *Proof.* on the first line of the alignment. Thanks in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\textit{Proof}.
\begin{align*}
    &= \textrm{a math equation here}\\
    &= \textrm{aligned properly}\\
    &= \textrm{blah blah blah}
\end{align*}
\vspace{-12px}
\hfill\rule{2mm}{2mm}\\
More text here to compare blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65191/204085) and its comments.

Comment: @Enevevet I don't think that's what I want. They did not mention `\begin{align*}` in the answer nor the comments.

Comment: @SandyG ok thanks. How do I close this problem without an answer?

Comment: @CELLSecret: The question has been marked as a possible duplicate. You don't have to do anything.