# QED box after equation inside lemma

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments, theorems

In a mathematical text, I have a lemma which I will just state and not proof. I want to give it a QED box at the end. Usually, I can just put the command `\qed` at the end of the lemma. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
  The reader is familiar with the following statement:

  \begin{lemma}
    If $a, b, c$ denote the sides of a rectangular triangle, and if $a$ denotes the longest side, then
    %
    \begin{equation*}
      a^2 = b^2+c^2.
    \end{equation*}
    \qed
  \end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

It produces a PDF-file which almost fits my desires:

[image: Output with \qed after the equation environment]

My problem is that the QED-symbol is too low. This happens because of the equation environment. The same problem appears in the `proof` environment, but in the `proof` environment it can be remedied by putting `qedhere` inside the equation environment.
Naively, I tried putting `\qedhere` inside my equation inside the lemma. The command had no effect, i. e. no QED box appeared. When I put `\qed` inside the equation environment like

```
\begin{equation*}
  a^2 = b^2+c^2. \qed
\end{equation*}
```

then I get the following, which I also dislike:

[image: Output with \qed inside the equation environment]

Is there an analogue of the `\qedhere` command that works in other environments than `proof`? If not, is there an easy way to get what I want?

I conferred these two posts:
[QED symbol after statements without proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334082/qed-symbol-after-statements-without-proof)
[How to make qed box inside alignment environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610970/how-to-make-qed-box-inside-alignment-environment)
But it seems that they both don't address my problem.

Comment: Why are you adding qed symbols inside lemmas in the first place? IMO they only belong at the end of proofs

Comment: Hi @daleif, I do so because I want to indicate that this lemma will not be proven. This post carries the spirit of my consideration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334082/qed-symbol-after-statements-without-proof
I am aware that this is a question of choice, so you may dislike my preferences.

Comment: I would write that in words instead of confusing the reader.

Comment: One way to diminish the vertical space between the equation and the qed sign, in this situation, is to add a \\[-1ex] at the end of the equation, but inside the equation environment.  Something like a^2 = b^2+c^2. \\[-1ex]

Answer (score 1):

You can use thmtools to define a `qedlemma` environment that always ends with a qed symbol, then use `\qedhere` inside the `equation*`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{lemma}
\declaretheorem[qed,name=Lemma,sibling=lemma]{qedlemma}

\begin{document}
The reader is familiar with the following statement:

\begin{qedlemma}
If $a, b, c$ denote the sides of a rectangular triangle, and if $a$ denotes the longest side, then
%
\begin{equation*}
  a^2 = b^2+c^2. \qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{qedlemma}

\end{document}
```

[image: lemma]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a wrapper environment `noproof` for statements that don't need a proof. You still need `\qedhere` if the statement ends with a display. You can use it with lemmas, propositions and even theorems.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{noproof}{m}{% #1 is the inner environment
  \par\pushQED{\qed}\UseName{#1}%
}{\popQED\UseName{end#1}}

\begin{document}

The reader is familiar with the following 
statements \ref{test1}~and~\ref{test2}.

\begin{noproof}{lemma}\label{test1}
If $a, b, c$ denote the sides of a rectangular triangle, and if 
$a$ denotes the longest side, then
\begin{equation*}
  a^2 = b^2+c^2.\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{noproof}

\begin{noproof}{lemma}\label{test2}
All animals are equal.
\end{noproof}

\begin{lemma}
This is unreferenced.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Easy exercise.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]